# Calculate daily change in value in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix with the following values: `a <- c(4,6,7,78,3,2,5,6,7,8)`

I would like to create a second matrix `b` which lists the changes in `a`'s value at each step.

So the solution would be: `b <- c(2,1,71,-75,-1,3,1,1,1)`

Is there a function for this in R and if there isn't what is the easiest way to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a <- c(4,6,7,78,3,2,5,6,7,8) #this is not a matrix in R btw
diff(a)
#[1]   2   1  71 -75  -1   3   1   1   1
```

Comment: thanks this is what I was looking for, now there's just one problem: since this creates a vector with a-1 values I cannot plot it against another vector that has 'a' values. Is there a way to impute a '0' as first value, indicating a '0' change for the 1st value?

Comment: `c(0,diff(a))`. Note that I have flagged the question for moderator attention, since it belongs on the sister site Stack Overflow, because it is essentially a question about programming. I expect it to be migrated soon.

Comment: Also, its a very basic question that tells us you would do well to read a few "intro to R" documents. Normally c(a,b) is learnt on day 1. You'll be asking a lot of questions here if you don't get a basic understanding first.